# Console.ReadLine() blocks Process output

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, console-application

Is there a better way to cancel a long-running task in a Console Application? This code is simplified, but exhibits the same exact issue as my larger application. The first method `Test1()` takes only 3 seconds as it blocks, but I want to be able to cancel this as the `GetStreamFromYoutubeDl` method will be apart of a larger `Task` that will run indefinitely.

For some reason the issue seems to reside in the `Console.ReadKey()` - or any variant of reading - method conflicting with reading the output of the Process. This can be easily seen as in `Test2()` if you input around 30 or so key presses the `Task` will immediately print it's output.

Adding the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` overload does not fix my issue either.

The full program is inlcuded

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Testing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Test 1 runs correctly, takes about 3 seconds
            //Test1();
            // Test 2 takes anywhere from 9 - 30 seconds, or hangs forever
            Test2();
        }

        static void Test()
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            // This blocks, which makes it run correctly
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetStreamFromYoutubeDl()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void Test2()
        {
            var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetStreamFromYoutubeDl());

            Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to exit.");
            while (true)
            {
                // Console.ReadKey here conflicts with the Process.StandardOutput.ReadLine for some reason, can confirm this
                // is the case as if you spam inputting keys, the process will output after ~30 or so key presses
                var read = Console.ReadKey(true);
                if (read.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
                {
                    cts.Cancel();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        static void GetStreamFromYoutubeDl()
        {
            var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            var url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbE1dL0iNkI";
            var youtubeDl = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                FileName = "youtube-dl",
                // 
                Arguments = $"{url} -g -f bestaudio --audio-quality 0",
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false
            };

            stopwatch.Start();
            var p = Process.Start(youtubeDl);

            if (youtubeDl == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to create youtube-dl process");
                return;
            }

            url = p.StandardOutput.ReadLine();

            stopwatch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(url + " " + stopwatch.Elapsed);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.ReadKey()` is a blocking operation if no key is yet pressed, so you could try testing with `Console.KeyAvailable` first.  You could also instead use the `Console.CancelKeyPress` event to invoke `cts.Cancel()` and not use `ReadKey` at all while still blocking as in `Test1`.  That does require Ctrl+C, and I'm not 100% sure whether it will resolve the std i/o conflict.

Comment: @sellotape How do I make it so the task will run on another thread so that the `ReadKey()` can block the main thread but the task will still run?

Comment: @sellotape I think you may be correct that testing with `KeyAvailable` fixes it

Comment: The way you have it now it will queue the task to the ThreadPool, so it should already be on a different thread.

Comment: Any idea on why then would the `Console.ReadLine()` block the other process's output?

Comment: @sellotape Oops, forgot to tag

Comment: Not really sure but [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx) has a section on deadlocking that can arise and how to get around it.  A google search for "console readline process redirect deadlock" turns up several related items.  The common theme seems to be to use the async methods instead.  Hopefully someone who knows more about this specific case comes along :)

Comment: Why `GetAwaiter().GetResult();` ? Why not just `.Result`? Did you copy this from some WinRT question?

Comment: Anyway, you *don't* need multithreading to start another process. `Process.Start` does *not* block. In fact, you have to do some extra work to wait for the child process to finish

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Starting the process isn't the issue, the issue has to do with doing a `Console.ReadLine()` and a `Process.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` And there does not seem to be a `.Result` in .NET 4.6.

Comment: @TristanMcPherson ????? Both [Task.Wait](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx) and [Task.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468(v=vs.110).aspx) are there since 4.0. Are you targeting WinRT perhaps? That's the only runtime that didn't have them

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos No, I'm not. The examples I saw used `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` so that's what i was. You're right though they are there. For some reason they weren't showing up earlier.

Comment: I have no idea what the desired behavior is here, and only a vague idea what the complaint is. Can you please clarify significantly?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example:

```
static void Test3()
{
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var processingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GetStreamFromYoutubeDl(),cts.Token);
    var readingFromConsoleTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press 'q' to exit.");
        while (true)
        {
            var read = Console.ReadKey(true);
            if (read.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
            {
                cts.Cancel();
                return;
            }
        }
    });

    Task.WaitAny(processingTask, readingFromConsoleTask);
}
```

The execution stops once any of the following happens: either processing task finishes or user will press 'q' to exit.